# How to find if a HTMLElement is enclosed in Selected text

Tags: javascript, selection, range

Is it possible to find out if an HTMLElement is totally enclosed within the selection?
I have a scenario where user selects some text in a HTML editor and applies some custom style from a list. Now I need to change the class attribute of each span element that is enclosed in that selection and surrounding the selection with a new span with the selected style.
Am able to find out if a particular span element is in selection by using DOM Range's compareBoundaryPoints method in firefox and safari but it will not work for IE.

Is there any way to find out if an element is totally enclosed with in the selected range for IE?

Thanks

Kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @standardModel says, Rangy gives you full* DOM Range support in IE and has a helpful [`getNodes()`](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#getNodes%28%5BArray_nodeTypes%5B,_Function_filter%5D%5D%29) method that you could use:

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var spans = range.getNodes([1], function(node) {
        return node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span" && range.containsNode(node);
    });

    // Do stuff with spans here
}
```

If you'd rather not use something as bulky as Rangy, the following function will tell you if an element is completely selected:

```
function isSelected(el) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var elRange = document.createRange();
        elRange.selectNodeContents(el);
        for (var i = 0, range; i < sel.rangeCount; ++i) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(i);
            if (range.compareBoundaryPoints(range.START_TO_START, elRange) <= 0
                    && range.compareBoundaryPoints(range.END_TO_END, elRange) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var elTextRange = textRange.duplicate();
        elTextRange.moveToElementText(el);
        return textRange.inRange(elTextRange);
    }
    return false;
}
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/54eGr/1/

(*) Apart from handling Range updates under DOM mutation

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim. I cannot use Rangy but your solution is perfectly working fine for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). This makes xbrowser Ranges and Selections a lot easier.

Comment: Specifically the CSS class applier module may help for this: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule